# I cant make my discord bot fetch messages and add it to an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("844038570167238710");
const fetchedMessage = channel.messages.cache.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
  const embedtest = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Test for embed send").setColor('#34d2eb').setFooter("Bot by").setThumbnail().setAuthor().setDescription(`${fetchedMessage}`);
  if (!fetchedMessage.author.bot) {
    message.channel.send(embedtest);
  }
}).catch(console.error);
```

I want the discord js bot to fetch messages from the channel add them in an embed and send them again to the same channel. I don't know why but this code isn't working.
Please help I'm stuck here for 1+ week.

Console log-

```
const fetchedMessage = channel.messages.cache.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:34:33)
```

Comment: You have `channel1` in your error code and `channel` in your bot code.  Which one is actually there?

Comment: Thats an old log thats why, i tried changing it to channel then too :(
Btw the const channel is channel id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is 3 errors in your example code .

1 . `channel1` is not defined it's `channel`.

2 . you assigned `fetchedMessage` is a promise not a result. And if it's right it can be Message object so we can access `fetchedMessage.content`

3 . `messages.cache.fetch()` is not exactly it is `messages.fetch()`.

So the working code will be :

**Note:** your execute function must be async

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("844038570167238710");
const fetchedMessage = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
// You can also do like this too 
const fetchedMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
const embedtest = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Test for embed send")
  .setColor("#34d2eb")
  .setFooter("Bot by")
  .setThumbnail()
  .setAuthor()
  .setDescription(`${fetchedMessage.content}`);
if (!fetchedMessage.author.bot) {
  message.channel.send(embedtest);
}
```

Comment: const fetchedMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
                       ^^^^^

Comment: It is throwing error in await in console log

Comment: Please read the note carefully I give you a noted already

Comment: sorry i didn't understand it

Comment: What part you didn't understand ?

Comment: the note Im not understanding why the code you sent is not working, can you send a working code? Thank you very much.

Comment: That will working one you should edit your message with more code that include your execute or run command function. Or you transform it into async function is ok. :D Async await is basic of javascript

Comment: thank you so much HellCatVN but are you there on discord ig that'll be a better place I have some more doubt about this?

Comment: You can mark this as solution and StackOverFlow will allow you to start chat conversation if you have more doubt

Comment: How can I start a conversation with you here, is there a place for messages I don't seem to find. thank you

Comment: HellCatVN#1235 my discord. Incase you can't find start conversation